# Camlp4 parser trace

Tags: ocaml, camlp4

I'm writing a simple parser with Camlp4.  The complexity is starting to get to the point where I am having trouble reasoning about the exact parse sequence.  What would be the best way to produce a "trace" of the parse that includes the tokens consumed and the rules matched.

E.g.  the following parser fragment:

```
let parse_func_call = parser
  | [< 'Token.Ident id; 'Token.LParen; 'Token.Ident id; 'Token.RParen >] -> ...
```

Might output a trace fragment like:

```
CONSUMED Ident
MATCHED parse_func_call
CONSUMED LParen
CONSUMED Ident
CONSUMED RParen
```

It doesn't appear that there's any such thing built in to Camlp4, so I'm wondering if its possible.

Comment: Of course you could log every rule fired...

Answer (score 0):

There exists `Camlp4Tracer` for ordinary function calls, maybe you could draw an inspiration from it and write a Camlp4Filter for the camlp4 grammar itself.. I am not to be held responsible if you go insane during that endeavour %)